# Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process on running console on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, server

I want to run rails console on heroku by typing command "heroku run rails console -a getpayad-staging" , but it kept on running and in logs i came up with error "Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process". I have seen couple of answers but not find perfect answer.

Comment: This question may have already been answered. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926403/heroku-rake-dbmigrate-results-in-error-r13-attach-error-failed-to-attach-t)

Comment: you should try with this answer, it worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21148716/1885672