# Heroku Django app: ECONNRESET: read ECONNRESET

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm getting the below error when trying to run the command `heroku run python manage.py migrate` from the terminal.

ECONNRESET: read ECONNRESET

I followed [the link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#timeout-awaiting-process) in the heroku docs to check if there was a firewall issue, but I had a successful telnet connection. I haven't been able to find any other examples of anyone running into this issue unless they are having a proxy/firewall issue but according to the telnet test it doesn't seem like I have a problem right?

I've also tried testing any other heroku run command I can think of and I get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the logs it showed that there was an Error Code R13. I was able to follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926403/heroku-rake-dbmigrate-results-in-error-r13-attach-error-failed-to-attach-t) to get what I needed to be fixed but was unable to run anything that needs to actually be attached (like an interactive shell).

Tried filing something with Heroku support but they basically said that it's outside the scope of free support. Disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with a proxy in your internet connection.
Try to connect to heroku by using another internet connection, for example your mobile phone tethering.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as a result of your internet connection provider blocking Heroku server. Change the source or provider of your internet and you will be able to connect to the Heroku Django console.